# Center UI elements in view with autolayout

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

How do you use Autolayout to make a UI Element centered left-to-right when in both landscape and portrait mode? Can you have variables in autolayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Interface builder to create & set position of your view, Select your View & do as the screenshot suggests below.

[image]

After that, click on "Add constraint" & you are done. This is just to set your view in horizontal centre. But you have to still add some more constraints. They are:

1. Height
2. Width
3. Distance from top/bottom layout guide/view.

Let me know if you don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

set constraints both vertical and horizontal

more understand autolayout easily follow this link

http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

[image]

output portait

[image]

output landscape

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your xib ,you should add 3 constraints :

1. Hirizontal Center in Container；
2. Width ;
3. Height ;

Comment: you have to add constraint for distance from top/bottom layout guide/view too… :)