# Button At Center of iPhone 3.5 and iPhone 4 inch using AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have simply Drag and button and set Image on it as following

[image]

Yet I have not used any CONSTRAINTS. As I run on iPhone 3.5 inch, it shows like below, where Button goes slightly down towards Y-Axis. [image]

I have TWO Questions here to ask.

**1. Which Constraints should I add to this Button?**

**2. Why these constraints are added, Simply I want to know Formula for calculating it.**

I would be thankful, If someone comprehensively describe my questions.

Thanks

Comment: Are you determined to solve this in IB, or are you open for code solutions as well? :-)

Comment: Both :D @MariusFalkenbergWaldal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:
This should be pretty easy in IB, using the Alignment Constraints dialog. Click the button, and in the Alignment Constraints, check Horizontal Center in Container and Vertical Center in Container. In the below collage, you can see how this centers the button on both 3.5 and 4 inch displays. 
(Don't forget to click the button "Add 2 constraints" :-)  )

Question 2:
Not sure what you are after... Formula?

[image: Interface Builder]

Answer (score 1):

1. select button
2. click *resolve autolayout issues* (bottom right)
3. add missing constraints

[image]

Comment: Did you read Questions which I posted. You answer is far away from Question. 
Please read it again. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 & 2:

It is depends on your requirement and layout design.

adding constraints for alignment or spacing, you can also use this menu to resolve layout issues, and determine constraint resizing behavior.

[image]

- **Align.** Create alignment constraints, such as centering a view in its
  container, or aligning the left edges of two views.
- **Pin.** Create spacing constraints, such as defining the height of a
  view, or specifying its horizontal distance from another view.
- **Issues.** Resolve layout issues by adding or resetting constraints
  based on suggestions (see “Resolving Auto Layout Issues”).
- **Resizing.** Specify how resizing affects constraints .

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH8-SW1

Comment: Dear, I read the documentation, but I am unable to get exact its usage.
Here, Let me know How will you show Button in center, only one UIButton, which must be in center of View in Both Sizes, 3.5 and 4 inch.

Comment: Simply start from first Question, How will you show button in center,

Comment: check horizontal & vertical center in container @Veer

Comment: @Veer  don't messed up. it is simple like a auto resizing method

Comment: I added Horizontal and vertical, but no use, see it   http://postimg.org/image/ix3rp2psz/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793542/center-ui-elements-in-view-with-autolayout/21794086#21794086

Comment: if possible link your project

Comment: drop box or github or mail me

Comment: Okay, I am mailing you, give me your email dear@iDev

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47555/discussion-between-veer-and-idev)